# On the Overwatch League viewer, when are the new matches added?

Tags: overwatch

Since June 6, 2019, the Overwatch League Replay Viewer has been [added once again](https://playoverwatch.com/en-us/news/23013835) on the region selector for PC owners.

I can see that the games of last week (June 6-9, 2019) are present, but not the ones that have been completed today (June 13, 2019) like [Outlaws vs Shock](https://overwatchleague.com/match/21392):

[image]

When are the new League matches added? Is some time after the match or at the end of the day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are added the Monday or Tuesday of the next week.

For example, the games from June 13 to June 16 are added either on June 17 or June 18.